# Does the term “pressure selling” have a legal origin?

Tags: legal-terms

Is it a pure colloquial term? Or does it have an origin in some article of legislation, or does (did?) it appear in some article of legislation?

Comment: I've edited the suggested duplicate answer with a footnote to cover this point